# Метод Main не завершается (java)

Tags: java

При старте miltithreading программы из **IDE (IDEA)** программа корректно работает, завершается, все потоки отрабатывают, все ресурсы закрыты. Но после сборки посредством **gradle** все тоже самое, только выполнение доходит до конца метода **main** и останавливается. Процесс не завершается, пока его принудительно руками не прибьешь. Но если в конец **main** добавить

```
System.exit(0);
```

То и после сборки **gradle** процесс завершается корректно. 
Почему так происходит? И можно ли что-то подкрутить, что бы избавиться от System.exit (по мне так это слишком коряво)?

Добавлено:
Gragle

```
group 'cherkasov.com'

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = "cherkasov.com.Manager"

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'        
    compile group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.4'        
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'utility'

    manifest.attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName,
            "Class-Path": configurations.runtime.files.collect { "$it.name" }.join(' '))

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}
```

Main

```
public class Manager {
    private final String[] args;
    private long workingTime = 0L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Manager manager = new Manager(args);

        manager.execute();

        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "End programm");

        System.exit(0);

    }
```

Лог выводит и далее висит (без System.exit). Потоки все создаются через

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCounter);
```

Фоновых потоков нет.

Comment: мало информации на мой взгляд, чтобы дать ответ

Comment: Для начала надо бы понять какие именно потоки не завершаются и на каком шаге они зависают.

Comment: О, тоже такое замечал. Воспроизводится, например, с асинхронным запросом посредством OkHttp.

Comment: Если вы сможете воспроизвести и привести [минимальный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (включающий в себя и код, и конфиг gradle) - шансы получить ответ увеличатся.

Comment: Вызывайте метод `shutdown` у `ExecutorService` в конце программы

Comment: @iksuy прав, после `service.shutdown()` программа стала завершаться корректно. Но осталось непонятно, почему в IDEA завершается корректно без ухищрений. И не понятно зачем `shutdown` нужен. Ведь все потоки завершаются и мы доходим почти до конца `main`. Ожидание чего происходит в самом конце?

Comment: @alexche Конец `main` означает завершение главного потока, однако потоки который создал `ExecutorService` не завержются, а программа завершается когда завершаются все потоки не являющиеся `демонами`.

Comment: @gt22 Так то оно так, только потоки все завершаются, о чем в логах пишется и управление передается дальше. И почему в IDEA потоки завершаются без `service.shutdown()`? Вопрос то возник после того как я в IDEA все протестировал, замечательно все работало, собрал gradl`ом и перестало работать. IDEA сама принудительно что ли потоки прибивает?

Comment: @alexche, да, вероятно как-то так и происходит в IDE. Почитайте вот здесь ответ первый, очень неплохо изложено про Threadы, думаю, сможете предположить, что делает IDE в этом случае.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219510/when-the-executorservice-shutdown-should-be-called

Comment: @alexche `ExecutorService` в варианте `FixedThreadPool` не уничтожает потоки пасле завершения задачи, тоесть когда вы пишете в логи завершается задача, но не поток, и он не даёт прогамме закрыться.